# is it possible to track GPS chip directly?

Tags: gps

i have GPS chip that i want to attach to the laptop. the idea is  to track the laptop wherever it go.

i have create a system and , the system installed in laptop is,

1st GPS acquire the location.

2nd laptop send the location to server

3rd server display it in web browser

but now i have a problem in this system, sometimes when laptop want to send the location to server (step2) it must connected to internet, and sometimes internet access in someplace is bad, signal strength in someplace is bad, so sometimes the internet is down and unable to send the location to server, this is the main problem , so i have an idea, how can i access that GPS chip location directly?

so the step will be.

1st GPS acquire the location.

2nd server seek GPS Chip location by Serial number of GPS chip

3rd server display it in web browser

is that posiible?

Comment: GPS only receive signal, you need internet to send position to the world.

Comment: No, it is not possible. GPS provides no such mechanism.

Comment: so that mean this is not possible, is it?

Answer (score 1):

No. GPS chips themselves are the only part of the system that can track their own location. You can't track a GPS chip without being in contact with the chip.

Comment: ok thanks for answer, i have been wondering this for an hour,